# Laravel 5.4 upgrade from Elixir to Webpack breaks js compilation with multiple SASS files

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-elixir

With Laravel 5.2's Elixir I used to be able to compile multiple SASS files into a single CSS file like so:

```
mix.sass([
        'app.scss',
        'controllers.scss'
    ], 'public/assets/css')
```

This no longer works. I now get this error:

```
mix.sass() is missing required parameter 1: src
```

Examining the new version of the function, it indeed wants a string and no longer knows what to do with an array.

I consulted the Laravel 5.4 docs on Webpack and the section about compiling multiple SASS files into a single CSS file has been removed, so I am presuming this functionality is now gone. What is the best way to compile multiple SASS files into a single CSS file using Webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use css's `@import` statement in a master .scss file, and then just tell webpack about that one file.

For example, if I have the scss files `style.scss` and `controllers.scss`, I might have the following `app.scss` file:

```
// App Styles
@import "style";

// Controller Styles
@import "controllers";
```

Then I will bundle that with webpack, with the following in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sourceMaps();
```

(Sourcemaps are optional, but they're very useful for debugging, as they enable developer consoles to tell you what line of code in your source files is causing a particular css rule. Without it, the dev console will tell you a line from `app.css`, and you'll be left guessing about where the original code actually is.)